# Excel formula for matching columns

Tags: excel

Have a column A with values in it  and a column C with values as well. Want formula to only show  the row where A & C values are different. How to do this and where to type out formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a header in columns A and C, in cell D2 you could put

`=A2-C2`

Dragging this down will show the differences in and cells. Taking this one step further, in cell D2 you could use

`=IF(A2<>C2,“Not Equal”,””)`

Dragging this down will show “Not Equal” for an cells where column A and C are different and blank for any cells that are equal.

You could then filter column D by “Not Equal” to just see the cells that are not equal.